# Red x next to documents and reports in tfs 2010 - how to fix this?

Tags: tfs

Suddenly red x appears next to documents and reports in one of ours TFS 2010 Project collections…

I have not changed anything related to user’s permissions – not sure why this happened.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that no changes related to users’ permissions are done, then you should try with clearing up Visual Studio Team Explorer cache.

For more details, you can check

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/08/19/how-to-clear-visual-studio-team-explorer-cache.aspx

Hope this helps, it helped me several times.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SharePoint Project Portal [Documents] and SSRS Site [Reports] up and running